# Wix not copying sql interop files in temprorary folder. Error Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll':

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, wix, windows-installer, setup-project

I am migrating one of my project from old vdproj to WIX project.
In my application installation i have to do some work during custom action on installation complete. I am successfully able to do other work but sqllite related implementation is not working as SQLite.Interop.dll files are not copying in temporary folder from where application install.
Bu After installation complete SQLite.interop file do able copied with other files in program menu folder.

My Wix setup xml is as following

...

```
  <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MyAppPosWixSetup" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="en_US_files" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="Images_files" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="_x64_files" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="_x86_files" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProgramFilesFolder_files" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="dlls_files" />
    </Feature>

 <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyAppPosWixSetup">
          <Directory Id="Images" Name="Images" />
          <Directory Id="_x64" Name="x64"  />
          <Directory Id="_x86" Name="x86" />
          <Directory Id="en_US" Name="en-US" />
          <Directory Id="dlls" Name="dlls" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id='AppDataFolder' Name='Roaming'>
        <Directory Id='_8F59BFDE_678A_D04A_B032_C90D66940878' Name='MyApp POS'>
          <Component Id='com_dir_8F59BFDE_678A_D04A_B032_C90D66940878' Guid='EECDB3BC-65C4-4A73-A182-2976A649713E' Transitive='no'>
            <CreateFolder Directory='_8F59BFDE_678A_D04A_B032_C90D66940878' />
            <RemoveFolder Id='_F53B4A9B_E7AA_4C30_A42F_DDF464B4A795' On='uninstall' />
            <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\Installer' Name='com_dir_8F59BFDE_678A_D04A_B032_C90D66940878' Type='string' Value='MyApp POS directory' KeyPath='yes' />
          </Component>
          <Component Id='com_B81229DC_FAC4_654D_B049_EC75EA79F23E' Guid='55A50D8C-2310-45A4-B8BF-54597EEE5B12' Permanent='no' SharedDllRefCount='no' Transitive='no'>
            <File Id='_B81229DC_FAC4_654D_B049_EC75EA79F23E' DiskId='1' Hidden='no' ReadOnly='no' System='no' Vital='yes' Compressed='yes' Name='config.ini' Source='..\PosControlApplication\config.ini' KeyPath='no' />
            <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\Installer' Name='com_B81229DC_FAC4_654D_B049_EC75EA79F23E' Type='string' Value='config.ini file' KeyPath='yes' />
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id='DesktopFolder' Name='Desktop'>
        <Component Id='com_dirDesktopFolder' Guid='064DDC54-0010-43F3-BCF3-8DCB8F9A0A87' Transitive='no'>
          <RemoveFolder Id='_FB2AC228_7D57_4311_9C65_34E7A5C1B266' On='uninstall' />
          <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\Installer' Name='com_dirDesktopFolder' Type='string' Value='Desktop directory' KeyPath='yes' />
          <Shortcut Id='_3DFA2BA1_17C7_0445_9809_A24D46646F71' Name='MyApp POS' Show='normal' WorkingDirectory='TARGETDIR' Target='[INSTALLFOLDER]PosControlApplication.exe'>
            <Icon Id='_A24D46646F71' SourceFile='..\PosControlApplication\Images\MyApp logo.ico' />
          </Shortcut>
        </Component>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="_x64_files" Directory="_x64">
      <Component Id="x64_SQLite.Interop.dll" Guid="13b928df-a28e-4163-af38-5cd5d87bf644">
        <File Id="x64_SQLite.Interop.dll" Name="SQLite.Interop.dll" Source="$(var.PosControlApplication_TargetDir)x64\SQLite.Interop.dll" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="_x86_files" Directory="_x86">
      <Component Id="x86_SQLite.Interop.dll" Guid="63874a2a-330d-42a0-bec1-09056dec2beb">
        <File Id="x86_SQLite.Interop.dll" Name="SQLite.Interop.dll" Source="$(var.PosControlApplication_TargetDir)x86\SQLite.Interop.dll" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
```

Also for testing purpose if i put a thread sleep in my custom code and added files manually to temporary folder my functionality do worked

Comment: Similar thing is mentioned at http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Use-files-in-temp-dir-during-installation-td7043096.html but without proper solution

Comment: You should say which files are not being installed because there are two sets of them, x64 and x86. Are none of them being installed? And if there's a custom action being called then show the definition and where it is called from. Certainly if your custom action is not deferred none of the files will be installed yet.

Comment: They are eventually installed in the program folder. but i can't see them in temp folder (wchich is created temprorary at insalled time)
Just for confirmation I put a sleep in my custom action class code and put manually folder of x86 and x64 there then i didn't get the error.

Comment: Unfortunately you haven't provided any of that info about the custom action, the package architecture, and you say they are supposed to be copied in a temporary folder and there is nothing about a temp folder in the WiX you've shown. You're just repeating the issue instead of providing the requested info.

Comment: you needed detail of custom action in xml or code?
I am basically a newbie in WIX. I have created a wix custom action dll in which Exit success event i am running a method. during that method i manipulate some ini file(which does successfully). In my main application there is a sql lite db is used. After installation i creates sql lite db and then a table in it. that was working in old vdproj. In wix installation i get sql interop file not load error. when i investigate i see there is no folder of x86 and x64 (these folders has sql lite interop dll) in a temproary folder which get created.

Comment: @PhilDW you need more info?

Comment: At the very least you need to show all of your WiX source, including the custom action specs and where they are called, the product and package specs.